# Angular - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get JSON from some website and then display it on my website using this line of code

```
<div class="item" ng-style="{'margin': mb.itemMargin()}" ng-repeat="item in mb.getItems()"> {{mb.calculateItemMargin()}} </div>
```

In ma .js file I'm using this code

```
mb.getItems = function($http){
    return $http.get("http://SOME_URL")
    .success(function(response) {
      return response.dirs;
    });
  };
```

But in console it shows this error:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**
>
> ```
> at mb.getItems (angular.js:56)
> at ib.functionCall (angular.js:12404)
> at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:12910)
> at n.$get.n.$digest (angular.js:14300)
> at n.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:14571)
> at angular.js:1455
> at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4203)
> at d (angular.js:1453)
> at uc (angular.js:1473)
> at Jd (angular.js:1367)
> ```

My angular.js file

```
var app = angular.module('mediaBrowserApp', []);
app.controller('mediaBrowser', function($http){
  var mb = this;
  

  mb.showMainPage = function (){
    if(mb.currentDir.length>0){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  };
  var dirToRedir = '';
  mb.dirContent = function(dir){
    mb.currentDir =  dir;
  };

  mb.nextDir = function(){
    return dirToRedir;
  };

  mb.calculateItemMargin = function(){
    var minWidth = 145;
    var minMargin = 17;
    var minElementWidth = minWidth + minMargin;

    var numOfItemsFitInContainer = 0;
    var widthOfParent = document.getElementById('mb-container').clientWidth;

    for(i=widthOfParent; i>minElementWidth; i = i-minElementWidth ){
      numOfItemsFitInContainer++;
    }

    var spaceLeft = widthOfParent - (minElementWidth * numOfItemsFitInContainer);
    if(spaceLeft>numOfItemsFitInContainer){
      var newItemMargin = minMargin + (spaceLeft/numOfItemsFitInContainer);
    }
    else{
      var newItemMargin = minMargin;
    }

    newItemMargin = newItemMargin / 2;

    return Math.floor(newItemMargin);
  };

  mb.itemMargin = function(){
    var width = mb.calculateItemMargin() + "px";
    return width;
  };

  mb.getItems = function($http){
    return $http.get("http://SOME_URL")
    .success(function(response) {
      return response.dirs;
    });
  };

});
```

Comment: can you post the full `ma.js` file? I suspect you are not injecting `$http`

Comment: You need to inject `$https` into your controller, not the function.

Comment: `$http` should be injected to controller!

Comment: add the 'ma.js' code for the controller..

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to inject services and providers to the functions themselves, but rather to the controller:

```
function($http) { // Lose this !
  ....
}
```

And place the `$http` injection in the controller declaration instead.

Comment: Seems to be working, but now I'm getting lots of errors, it looks like it is in some loop or something because there are around 100 errors printed in a console every second

Comment: One by one... :) Paste one maybe we can see what it is.